# загрузка информации из папки raw

Tags: java, android

Есть текстовый файл загруженный в папке raw заполнен в столбик допустим такими записями:

```
abc
bac 
knc
```

Можно ли как-нибудь вывести из этого файла данные в `listview`?

Помогите выделяет красным строку в моем коде

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(layout.fragment_search, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.fr2);
        listView=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(id.lst);
        editText=(EditText) rootView.findViewById(id.txtsearch);
        initList();
        editText.clearFocus();
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(s.toString().equals("")){
                    // Обновление listview
                    initList();
                } else {
                    // выполнение поиска
                    searchItem(s.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                FragmentTransaction tr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                String currPos = listItems.get(position);
                if (currPos.equals(textPos0)) {
                    //Создание нового фрагмента и транзакции
                    Fragment Stay1 = new Stay1();
                    // Замените все, что есть в представлении fragment_container, этим фрагментом,
                    //И добавьте транзакцию в задний стек
                    tr.replace(R.id.container, Stay1);
                    tr.addToBackStack(null);
                    //Завершить транзакцию
                    tr.commit();
                }
                else if (currPos.equals(textPos1)) {
                    Fragment Stay2 = new Stay2();
                    tr.replace(R.id.container, Stay2);
                    tr.addToBackStack(null);
                    tr.commit();
                } else if (currPos.equals(textPos3)){
                    Fragment Stay3 = new Stay3();
                    tr.replace(R.id.container, Stay3);
                    tr.addToBackStack(null);
                    tr.commit();
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public List<String> getTextFromRaw() {
        List<String> arr1 = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.stm);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                arr1.add(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arr1;
    }

    public void searchItem(String textToSearch){
        textToSearch = textToSearch.toLowerCase();
        for(String item:items){
            if(!item.toLowerCase().contains(textToSearch)){
                listItems.remove(item);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    //передача результатов поиска в listview
    public void initList(){
        List<String> arr1 = getTextFromRaw();
        //String [] arr1;
        //arr1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stops);
        items=arr1;
        listItems=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout.list_item, id.txtitem, listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        textPos0 = listItems.get(0);
        textPos1 = listItems.get(1);
        textPos3 = listItems.get(9);
    }
items=arr1; вот эту
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример как можно прочитать данные из файла в папке raw

```
public List<String> getTextFromRaw() {
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        int count = 0;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            strList.add(line);
            count++;
            if (count==10){
                break;
            }
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strList;
}
  List<String> strList = getTextFromRaw();        
  ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strList);
  listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: в строке (R.raw.test); выделяет красным тест

Comment: @Joel вместо `test` название вашего файла

Comment: а с расширением или без?

Comment: без. При введение `R.raw.` у вас должно вывестись список файлов в вашей папке raw

Comment: А-ев если вы ещё тут можно как нибудь вывести определенное количество строк допустим первые 10?

Comment: @Joel Обновил ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: а если оставшиеся надо вывести допустим после 10?

Comment: `if (count > 10) {
                    strList.add(line);
                }
                count++;`

Comment: последний вопрос честно как подключить два файла в одной активити?

Comment: @Joel Так добавьте еще один `InputStream` и работайте с ним.

Comment: А буффер новый надо?